# Which are the best universities for a DPhil/PhD in proof theory and automated reasoning?

Tags: soft-question, career

I'm an undergraduate student studying computer science and I'm interested in doing a PhD after I graduate. I would like to do research in proof theory and automated reasoning, specifically in automated theorem proving and mainly the theory behind these areas (I don't like implementation that much). Which universities are specialized in these fields?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm aware of at least two perfect places.

1. Paris and suburbs. You might want to check websites of David Baelde/Gilles Dowek (ENS Paris-Saclay), Delia Kesner (IRIF), Dale Miller (INRIA Saclay).
2. Vienna. There is a strong group of Agata Ciabatoni and of Roman Kuznets.

You also might check the list of the accepted papers for LICS/CSL/MFCS/FOSSACS/ESOP/JELIA and see the authors of the papers that seem to be related to proof theory.

Comment: BTW, both places offer masters scholarships so you might be interested in doing your master studies there. I did the first year of masters in Cachan and the plus is that after each year you do a 3-6 months research internship in the topic you like.